# Can Javascript check a file for content changes?

Tags: javascript

Example:

I have

```
var r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = function(e) {
        drawGraph(r.result);
    }
    r.readAsText(f);
```

drawing a graph from the file f input by the user.

Is there a way to check to see if the file f has been changed and then re load it's content without needing for the user to pick the file again?

Comment: Could I refresh the file? instead of waiting for it to change, just update the graph periodically automatically, or do I need user input for that?

Comment: You need user input for that.

Comment: are you building a web app? i think you can do this in javascript with a chrome app.

Comment: A chrome app might work, thanks, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved using Node.js's filesystem API which provides a "watch" function

NodeJS Filesystem API docs: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Similar question:
[Observe file changes with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698043/observe-file-changes-with-node-js)

```
fs.watch('somedir', function (event, filename) {
    console.log('event is: ' + event);
    if (filename) {
        console.log('filename provided: ' + filename);
    } else {
        console.log('filename not provided');
    }
});
```