# Event handler on file change and get changes in file using NodeJS File System

Tags: node.js, fs

I want to watch a specific file to look for specific changes using Node and also fetch those changes in the file. Is there anyway doing that using **fs**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Observe file changes with node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698043/observe-file-changes-with-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it by using **fs**.

How to do it:

1. Load file content
2. Watch file
3. Compare content with the previous one when `change` event is triggered
4. Update file content

It should look like this:

```
fs.watch('foo', function (event, filename) {
  if (event == 'change') {
    // Load file content
    // Compare to one previously loaded
    // actualContent = newContent
  }
});
```

See:

- fs.watch documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener
- Event change documentation: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_event_change