# How to get data row by row from a xlsx file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, excel

i am facing an issue where i need to get data from an xl file and convert the record or row to a json format and send it to a server so the issue here is the file gets changed frequently(mean new data will be added data will be appended to new rows) so for every change we need to send the added data to server i have come up with a logic to make a note of last row i have send to server and when there is change from previous variable that stores last row sent i will send rows from that variable to last row .

**so i want to know is there a way to just make a refernce to a xlsx file rather than loading the whole file and getting row by row data**

mycode it doesnt work that way:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var XLS= require('xlsx');

var book = XLS.readFile('test.xlsx');

var sheet_name_list = book.SheetNames[0];
var Sheet1 = book.Sheets[sheet_name_list];
//console.log(Sheet1);


var j = XLS.utils.sheet_to_json(Sheet1['A17']);
console.log(j);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is observe file changes, node.js has `[fs.watch][1]` method for this

[Observe file changes with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698043/observe-file-changes-with-node-js)

you need reread file every time that you get change event.

Also you can try to use `excel-js` package and reading xlsx via `Stream`, but I'm not sure is it send you updates while you adding rows

Comment: i know about fs.watch i want to take data from xl file row by row so that i can get updated data

Comment: try to play with streams, may be you can read the xlsx row somehow from it