# "Automate JSON Files upload to Blob Storage"

Tags: json, azure, salesforce, azure-blob-storage

Automatic JSON Files upload to Blob Storage.

Description:
We have a SSIS job which will generate JSON files with data at a server path. We are manually copying the JSON files and dropping them in BLOB storage in order to trigger our logic app.

Now, Could anyone help to provide information on how we can automate the process of copying JSON files to BLOB automatically? ( Like do we have any approach or code to copy the JSON files at a specific time and copy those JSON files in BLOB )

Comment: Is your server on azure? do you want to copy it to blob storage only 1 time or like every day? and which code(.net , python) do you prefer?

Comment: Hi Yang, Server would be our local server from where files need to consume, we want to copy to the blob storage daily for a specific time(we can consider as a daily job) We are using Dot net for the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to listen to the file system change at your server path, then to use Azure Storage SDK to upload these files which be triggered by the file changed event.

As reference, here are some resources about the API or SO threads of file changes listener in different languages, because I don't know what language you want to use.

1. C# [FileSystemWatcher Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8)
2. Python [How do I watch a file for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes)
3. Node.js [Observe file changes with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698043/observe-file-changes-with-node-js)

For other languages, I think you can easily get their solution by searching. And to upload files to Azure Storage, you just need to refer to Azure offical getstarted tutorials in dfferent languages to write your code.