# Angular custom file change detection

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am building an Angular app that uses markdown files (.md) to generate my terms of use, privacy policy, etc. pages.

```
/help
 +- terms-of-use.component.md
 +- terms-of-use.component.html
 +- terms-of-use.component.ts
```

I have a custom script that converts the .md files to html and it is registered as prestart and prebuild steps:

```
package.json file excerpt...

"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "node transformMarkdown.js",
    "start": "ng serve --host localhost --port 4200 --disable-host-check --configuration local",
    "prebuild": "node transformMarkdown.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
},
```

And it works great! Whenever I run `npm run start` or `npm run build`, my script detects that the .md file has changed and updates the html file. For example:

```
> npm run start
> artistry@0.0.0 prestart
> node transformMarkdown.js

Generating... terms-of-use.component.html

> artistry@0.0.0 start
> ng serve --host localhost --port 4200 --disable-host-check --configuration local
```

Now I am trying to get Angular to auto-detect the .md file changes and regenerate the html file automatically just it would with a change to any other file. I cannot figure out how to do this.

I believe that at its core, the problem lies in (not just in file change detection), but also that I launched ng serve using node (npm start). Is it possible to get this to work by just using ng serve (and have it detect the .md file changes)?

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can watch another type of file in Angular but it is possible in your custom script to use the Nodejs file api to see the changes

[Watch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698043/observe-file-changes-with-node-js)